# Derivation First variation formula of a functional

Tags: calculus-of-variations

**I did not understand two transitional stages in the red rectangulars. (Please look question marks)
Could you help me?**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The first rectangle is simple Taylor expansion. And the second rectangle is just a definition for the "first variation"

Comment: Thank you for interest. Can you explain some more details about how to get that equality from Taylor expansion? I know Taylor expansion for multivariable functions but I don't understand this.

Comment: But the first box is exactly the first order expansion of the function $f(x,y+\epsilon \eta,  y'+\epsilon \eta')$. What part do you not understand?

Comment: I don't understand the first order expansion of the function , unfortunately :/

Comment: The last few lines on [this](http://www.math.ucdenver.edu/~esulliva/Calculus3/Taylor.pdf) website might help.Take a=x ; b=$\eta\epsilon$ ; c=$\eta'\epsilon'$